# Where are "scopes" of the sites?

Tags: support

I sometimes get my questions closed as "offtopic" because they don't belong to the site's scope.

Whenever I visit a new SE site I try to see where is its scope defined, but cannot find it.

Why isn't there an easy way to see it? Or what am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Up in the top right, under the `help v` drop-down, there are two important links:

[image]

The first goes to [the tour](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour), and the second goes to [the help center](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help). Both contain a lot of valuable information about the current site, in different formats (one as a walk-through, and one as a series of FAQs).

If you've been through there and have a specific question you don't feel is answered there, follow the third link, which brings you here. You can search for previously asked questions that might provide an answer, and if that still proves unhelpful, ask your specific question.

Answer (score 1):

The "[Help Center -> What topics can I ask about here?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" page gives a rough overview of the scope of each SE site, lining up what is and what is not ontopic.

However this is not necessarily an exhaustive enumeration of all possible topics.